# how to write reflection function on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a table

```
Id    PId   code 
12    10    abca
13    12     wwr
14    13     sdf
15    14     aba
16    15     wqe
```

i need to  replace the  PIDs with parent ID Like

```
Id    PId   code 
12    10     abca
13    12     wwr
14    12     sdf
15    12     aba
16    12     wqe
```

this is my basic need to replace with all child PId 
i think we need to  write a recursive function  and need to replace 
im using sql server 2008 rs , tell me the best way how can i achieve this

Comment: So you want to replace any `PId` with `12` instead of the `null` one (id=12)?

Comment: What is the relationshiop between parent and child.

Comment: Removed `plsql` tag as this seems to be for SQL Server only (no mentioning of Oracle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand it, you now have a hierarchy, with a link from top through children to bottom, and you want to change it so that each children in the hierarchy points to the top most parent.

Alternative i don't like: Cursor + a while cyclus to find the topmost record for each row

Thew way i would do it: (not tested, may got some bugs, writen out of head)

```
with RecursiveCTE as (
    select ID as TopID,
           ID as ID
      from Table where PId is null
    union all
    select TopID,
           ID
      from Table
      join RecursiveCTE on RecursiveCTE.ID = Table.PId
)
update Table
   set PId = TopID
  from Table
  join RecursiveCTE
    on RecursiveCTE.ID = Table.ID
 where Table.PId is not null
```

Response to comment: Now, that depends on WHAT exactly you trying to do. In case there is no null case...does that mean there is a cycle? (very bad and not easy to do, has to be checked for) Or do you know the starting value? In that case all you have to do is change the

```
from Table where PId is null
```

to

```
from Table where PId = 10
```

and change

```
where Table.PId <> TopID
```

to

```
where Table.PId is not null
```

Comment: thanks for u  r reply could you please review my question one more time  please ... if there no null cases how i need to handle it ..TIA